# How can I import an existing React component defined in JSX in a Typescript module (.tsx)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsc

I have an existing React component that's coded in JSX and I can't convert to Typescript at this time.   I'd like to make use of it in a new React application that is being written in Typescript.   I cannot figure out if it's possible to import and use the JSX code within the TSX code.   Is this possible?   How do I do it?

Thanks

The example below gives the error:  `TS2604:JSX element type 'OldCode' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

OldCode.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>OldCode</div>
  }
})
```

NewCode.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { OldCode } from './OldCode';

export default class NewCode extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <OldCode/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I gave up on using Typescript for this project and never tracked down why @djwwwww's answer didn't work for me.  My instinct says it's right, but since I couldn't confirm, I didn't mark it accepted.

Comment: Try this in tsx to import jsx: `const NewCode = require('./NewCode').default;`

Answer (score 1):

```
declare module '*.jsx' {
    var _: React.Component<any, any>;
    export default _;
}
```

and use it like

```
import OldCode from './OldCode.jsx';
```

put this in some file, make sure it's included in `tsconfig.json`.

and of course, make sure webpack packs them all.

Comment: this sounds like the right track, but I've tried it and still get the same error.  Perhaps I misunderstood an instruction?  I've created a new file `jsx_compat.tsx` in the same directory as OldCode.jsx that holds your first block and added `jsx_compat.tsx` to my tsconfig.json.

Comment: Sorry, can't edit the comment above where I hit enter too soon.

this sounds like the right track, but I've tried it and still get the same error.  Perhaps I misunderstood an instruction?  I've created a new file `jsx_compat.tsx` in the same directory as OldCode.jsx that holds your first block and added `jsx_compat.tsx` to my tsconfig.json.  I've also modified my import statements to match.  

Any  more suggestsion?

I will remember to make sure webpack packs them all, but right now, I'm failing at the call to `tsc`.

Comment: @Jobu here is an example of how you import other-than-ts modules, https://github.com/webgl-component/core. And what error did `tsc` generate?

Comment: thanks I'll read the example.   The error message from tsc is `TS2604:JSX element type 'OldCode' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Comment: @Jobu try putting the module definitions in `.d.ts` files.

Comment: Just tried renaming to jsx_compat.d.ts and no change.   It seems like your recommendation is straight out of https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6615 and I'm using tsc 2.1.4, so I'm guessing I'm missing something arcane at this point, but I can't guess what that might be.

Comment: @Jobu did you include `.d.ts`, I just tried, it worked for me.

Comment: when you say "include .d.ts" what do you mean?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/joesonw/946019d08eadcda00ecbc539dcc29b31, and compile it with `tsc --allowJs -p tsconfig.json`

Comment: thanks for trying, but no  change for me.   I'm going to take a break and go over OldCode.jsx with fresh eyes and hope I see something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131933/discussion-between-jobu-and-djwwwww).

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing your import statement:

```
import OldCode from './OldCode';
```

If you are using webpack you may need to add .jsx to your resolvers too.

Comment: thanks for taking a look, but changing the import syntax doesn't change the results.   I do have .jsx in my webpack resolvers, but that's downstream from here.  I need tsc to be able to compile the tsx first.

Answer (score -1):

Since there's no accepted answer I will link to my question that actually answers how to write a definition file for an existing component (my question is about a component wrapped in a redux connect):

[[How do I create a typescript definition file (d.ts) for an existing redux connected (jsx)component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508800/how-do-i-create-a-typescript-definition-file-d-ts-for-an-existing-redux-connec][1])

Hope it helps someone...

Comment: You can add a comment to the question, and your [so] link will show up in the sidebar under _Linked_. There's no need to add an answer with no solution.