# How do I create a typescript definition file (d.ts) for an existing redux connected (jsx)component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, jsx, tsx

I'm adding new components written in TypeScript(tsx) to an existing codebase consisting of vanilla ES6 react components(jsx). When importing the existing jsx-components into a tsx-component I'm adding type defintions for the jsx-components.

**My issue is how do I add a type definition for a jsx-component that is connected to redux using connect**

Say I have an existing jsx component:

```
class DateField extends React.Component {
...
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    locale: state.systemUser.language.langKey
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (DateField);
```

**How would a typedefintion look like for this component?**

Note: without the connect I would write the typedefinition like:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as moment from "moment";

export type IonDateFieldChange = (value: string | Date | moment.Moment) => void;
export interface IDateFieldProps {
  value: string | Date | moment.Moment
  onChange?: IonDateFieldChange
  placeholder?: string
}
declare class DateField extends React.Component<IDateFieldProps,any> {}
```

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? If so please answer your own question.